# Foreach binding with "as" alias does not work correctly in IE9

Tags: knockout.js, internet-explorer-9

I can't get the for-each to work correctly in IE9, however works in IE10, IE11

Is there anything wrong with the way I have it? The following code can be used to reproduce the issue in IE9:

```js
var vm = {
    MyMessages: [{
        MessageType1: 'A',
        MessageToShow1: 'B '
    }]
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: {data: MyMessages, as: 'foo'} "  class="list-unstyled">
    <li>
        <div>
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
            <em><label data-bind='text: foo.MessageType1' /></em>
            <label data-bind='text: foo.MessageToShow1' />
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The error I get is that:

> 'foo' is undefined

Comment: I've taken the liberty of changing up your code so it's an actual repro. I could confirm the issue with this code. It was meant to help, but if you feel I've changed your question to radically please feel free to roll back my edits.

Comment: Just a blind shot in the dark but does quoting the property fix it? i.e., `foreach: {data: MyMessages, 'as': 'foo'}`

Comment: @Jeff Just tried in a jsfiddle with IE11 set to render in 9 document mode, get the error with or without quoting `as`

Comment: Having said that, removing the `as` and binding directly to `MessageType1` and `MessageToShow1` is resulting in an error too...

Comment: [Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dgyg2ytr/) - works fine in Chrome & IE11, but switch IE11 to 9 mode and you see an error.  Looks to be a bug in knockout affecting `foreach` in general?

Comment: I dont see why you need to name it foo. Why cant you just use $data and make the data-bind be data-bind='foreach: MyMessages' ?

Comment: @segFault You may have more than one `foreach` nested - using `as` allows you to be specific as to which one you're referring to.  This is just an example showing a problem, in this instance you're right, you wouldn't really need to use it.

Comment: Good point I didn't think of that.

Comment: I tried to debug through this and noticed something odd. I used [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7c7c0e2m/).  I have IE 10 and in browser mode 10, setting a breakpoint on line 2880, it hits the breakpoint 2 times.  In browser mode 9, it hits it 5 times. It looks like it might be misclassing one of the child elements applying more bindings than it should.

Comment: FWIW it hits that line 3 times in both IE11 and Chrome...!

Comment: @JamesThorpe: Sorry, miscounted, I didn't count the initial break. I had to continue 2 times after the break.

Comment: I only used 'as' as a desperate attempt to solve the issue. It is not needed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tl;dr:  Write out the `label` tags with an open and close tags.

It appears when rendering in IE 9 mode, IE is misclassing some of the elements due to the use of "self-closing" tags.  The `label` is one such tag.  Since by being in IE 9 mode, it is also not using standards (HTML5) mode.  IE 10 mode will render it in standards mode.  So depending on the mode, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5) indicates how the tag is interpreted differs.

I guess that in IE 9, it's seeing the tag as an open tag without a closing tag so is applying the bindings to the wrong elements.

By changing the labels to use open and close tags, it seems to fix it.

```html
<ul data-bind="foreach: {data: MyMessages, as: 'foo'} "  class="list-unstyled">
    <li>
        <div>
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
            <em><label data-bind='text: foo.MessageType1'></label></em>
            <label data-bind='text: foo.MessageToShow1'></label>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7c7c0e2m/1/

Comment: Nice catch.  Verified it in my non-`as` fiddle too.

Comment: also found that changing the label to a span just fixed the issue too.